# Why do my dropdowns show the message "array(1) ..." for each dependent drop down?

Tags: php, jquery, mysql, arrays, cascadingdropdown

I am designing a page that gathers study abroad information from students at my university. Each time you select a country, the drop down will then say array(1) { ["country"]=> string(6) "France" } (or a similar country) before it says "State:". Why is this?

Below is my code minus the UUID and the database connection.

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<head>
<link href="Page2.css" rel="stylesheet">
<style>
.error {
 color: #FF0000;
}
</style>
    <link href="styles.css" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css"/>
    <script type="text/javascript" src="//code.jquery.com/jquery-1.10.2.js"></script> 
    <script src="http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.9.0/jquery.min.js"></script>
 <script type="text/javascript" src="http://code.jquery.com/ui/1.8.23/jquery-ui.min.js"></script> 
 <script type="text/javascript">
 
 function go() {
  var Count = document.getElementById("sa_yesno").options[document.getElementById("sa_yesno").selectedIndex].value;
   if(Count==1) {
    document.getElementById("info").style.display = 'none';
   }
    if(Count==2) {
      document.getElementById("info").style.display = '';
      }
      }
 
    $(document).ready(function(){
        
        $("select#countryName").change(function() {
         var country = $("select#countryName option:selected").attr('value');
         //alert(country);
         $("#state").html("");
         $("#city").html("");
         if (country.length > 0 ) {
          //alert(country.length);
          $.ajax({
           type: "POST",
           url: "fetch_state.php",
           data: "country="+country,
           cache: false,
           success: function(html) {
            $("#state").html( html );
           }
           //not sure about these last two parts
          
          });//end ajax
         }//end if
        });//end countryName.change
    });
 </script>
<header>
<h1> University </h1>
<h2> Department </h2>
</header>  
</head>
<?php
 require 'dbc.php';
 require 'uuid.php';
    
    $countriesSQL = "SELECT DISTINCT Country FROM LOCATIONLOOKUP";
    $countriesQuery = mysqli_query($conn, $countriesSQL);
    while($countries[] = $countriesQuery->fetch_object());
    array_pop($countries);
    
?>


<body>
<table><tr><td>
<div class="StyleDiv" > 
<form action="Page3.php" method="post">

<p> Please share any of the information below that you are comfortable sharing about your study abroad experience, if applicable.</p>
<p> 1. Did you study abroad? </p>

<p><select onchange="go()" name="sa_yesno" id="sa_yesno">
<option value="1">No</option> 
<option value="2">Yes</option> 
 
</select></p>

<div class="styleDiv" id="info" style="display:none">

<p> 2. When did you study abroad? </p>

<p><select name="sa_term" id="sa_term">
<option value="Fall">Fall Semester</object> 
<option value="Spring">Spring Semester</object> 
<option value="J-term">J-Term</object> 
<option value="Summer">Summer Term</object> 
</select></p>

<p> Where did you study abroad?</p>

 Country: <select name="countryName" id="countryName">
  <option value="">Please Select</option>
   <?php foreach($countries as $option) : ?>
  <option value="<?php echo $option->Country; ?>"><?php echo $option->Country; ?></option>
   <?php endforeach; ?>
 </select></br>
 <div id="state" class="cascade"></div>
 <div id="city" class="cascade"></div>

<br/><br/>
<input type="submit" value="Continue" name="submit" id="submit" ONCLICK="window.location.href='Page3.php?'">
</div>
</form>

<?php
 require 'dbc.php';
 require 'uuid.php';

 $studentID = $_SESSION["studentID"];
 $studyid=null;
 
 //can these be assigned values in the select tag above?
 $countrySelected= $_POST["countryName"];
 $stateSelected= $_POST["drop2"];
 $citySelected= $_POST["drop3"];
 
 //Select the locationID from the country, state, city that were specified
 $sql2 = "SELECT LocID FROM LOCATIONLOOKUP WHERE Country = '" . $countrySelected . "'
  AND StateProvince = '" . $stateSelected . "' AND City = '" . $citySelected . "';";
 $result2 = mysqli_query($conn, $sql2);
 if (!$result2) {
      $message  = 'Invalid query: ' . mysql_error() . "\n";
      $message .= 'Whole query 2: ' . $query;
      die($message);
      echo "there was an issue";
}
while ($row = mysqli_fetch_assoc($result2)) {
    $locationID = $row['LocID'];
}

   
$stmt = $conn->prepare(" INSERT INTO STUDYABROAD (Term, StudentID, LocID)  VALUES ( ?, ?, ?, ?)");
$stmt->bind_param("ssss", $term, $studentID, $locationID);
$stmt->execute();

 
 mysqli_close($conn);
?>

</body>
</html>
```

EDIT: Here is fetch_state.php

```html
<?php

require 'dbc.php';
var_dump($_POST);
$country = trim(mysqli_escape_string($conn, $_POST["country"]));

$sql = "SELECT DISTINCT StateProvince FROM LOCATIONLOOKUP WHERE Country = '". $country ."' ORDER BY StateProvince";
$count = mysqli_num_rows( mysqli_query($conn, $sql) );
if ($count > 0) {
$query = mysqli_query($conn, $sql);
while($states[] = $query->fetch_object());
    array_pop($states);
?>
<label>State:
<select name="state" id="drop2">
 <option value="">Please Select</option>
 <?php foreach($states as $option) : ?>
        <option value="<?php echo $option->StateProvince; ?>"><?php echo $option->StateProvince; ?></option>
         <?php endforeach; ?>
</select>
</label>
<?php
 }
?>



<script src="jquery-1.9.0.min.js"></script>
<script>
$(document).ready(function(){


$("select#drop2").change(function(){

 var state = $("select#drop2 option:selected").attr('value');
   // alert(state_id);
 if (state.length > 0 ) { 
  $.ajax({
   type: "POST",
   url: "fetch_city.php",
   data: "state="+state,
   cache: false,
   success: function(html) {    
    $("#city").html( html );
   }
  });
 } else {
  $("#city").html( "" );
 }
});

});
</script>
```

Comment: Did you provide the code of the file "fetch_state.php"? Probably, there is var_dump there. Remove it, and the text will disappear.

Comment: you have used var_dump($_POST); on line 2 just remove this

Comment: why the whole while()/array_pop? Why not just use a `fetch_all()` call,which gives you a nice array to start with?